# I need help adding Databases in firebase

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to learn firebase to build apps more easily, but I've been having slight issues with adding databases to the server.

Here is the code:

```
import pyrebase as pb

fbconfig = {"apiKey": "AIzaSyCy5R9rbQWt4AzBo5sZeGBKcoyfHZ1fD-s",
            "authDomain": "fir-fb8e9.firebaseapp.com",
            "databaseURL": "https://fir-fb8e9.firebaseio.com",
            "projectId": "fir-fb8e9",
            "storageBucket": "fir-fb8e9.appspot.com",
            "messagingSenderId": "816508440796",
            "appId": "1:816508440796:web:e03ef3c4810606f8faa419",
            "measurementId": "G-0MWJ5YES8M"}
fb = pb.initialize_app(fbconfig)
db = fb.database()
d1={"age":16,"Name":"Ebraheem Alrawi","Group":"For Fun"}
db.push(d1)
```

I tried changing the databaseURL links over and over again but it would give me the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Test\PycharmProjects\speedplate\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 503, in raise_detailed_error
    request_object.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\Test\PycharmProjects\speedplate\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://fir-fb8e9.firebaseio.com/.json

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Test/PycharmProjects/speedplate/firebasetest/main.py", line 34, in <module>
    db.push(d1)
  File "C:\Users\Test\PycharmProjects\speedplate\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 310, in push
    raise_detailed_error(request_object)
  File "C:\Users\Test\PycharmProjects\speedplate\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 507, in raise_detailed_error
    raise HTTPError(e, request_object.text)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://fir-fb8e9.firebaseio.com/.json] {
  "error" : "404 Not Found"
}


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried searching in google but there were no results

Comment: Does `db.child("").push(d1)` work ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Pyrebase documentation found https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#database

Create a database reference location.

```py
db = firebase.database()
db.child("users").child("Morty")
```

Save data with an auto-generated key.

```py
data = {"name": "Mortimer 'Morty' Smith"}
db.child("users").push(data)
```

Define your own keys use the set() method.

```py
data = {"name": "Mortimer 'Morty' Smith"}
db.child("users").child("Morty").set(data)
```

Update data for an existing entry.

```py
db.child("users").child("Morty").update({"name": "Mortiest Morty"})
```